# Select specified column from sqlite database and show to textview

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

UPDATE!!!!

I'm working with android sqlite database, I want to select a specified query using sql select statement with where clause like this "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Name'";

but I don't success with, this is my code that works but don't contain any where clause.
Thanks.

```
public String Read(String name)
{
    String[] columns = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NPM, SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME};
    String selection = SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " = " + name;
    String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(name)};
    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_MHS, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);


    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String index_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME));
    return index_name;
}
```

I put that code on my database source that extends sqliteopenhelper, but I got following error in log cat

`03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: radit: , while compiling: SELECT npm, name FROM Mhs WHERE name = radit
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1438)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1317)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1271)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1353)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at com.crud.MhsDataSource.Read(MhsDataSource.java:55)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at com.crud.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-10 11:57:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(14709):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

I've got the answer, this is my code for SQLite select parameter

```
public String Read(String name)
{
    String[] columns = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NPM, SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME};
    String selection = SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " like ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = {name};
    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_MHS, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);


    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String index_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME));
    String index_npm = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NPM));
    String result = index_npm + " " + index_name;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause is the 3d parameter and the where args is the 4th.

You should do something like:

```
public String Read(String name)
{
    String[] columns = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NPM, SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME};
    where = "Name=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{name};

    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_MHS, columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);

    //....
}
```

Check [www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for details